# IDFT of voltage frequency response of input resistance of antenna / transmission line is non causal?

Tags: frequency-response, impulse-response

Always seem to get this effect when I specifically do the real part of an input impedance over divided by the input impedance in the frequency domain:

I have a lossless transmission line with no source resistance

$$ H(f) =\frac{Re[Z_{in}(f)]}{Z_{in} (f)} = \frac{Re\left[50 \frac{125 + 50 i \tan \left(\right. \frac{2 \pi f l}{c} \left.\right)}{50 + 125 i \tan \left(\right. \frac{2 \pi f l}{c} \left.\right)}\right] }{50 \frac{125 + 50 i \tan \left(\right. \frac{2 \pi f l}{c} \left.\right)}{50 + 125 i \tan \left(\right. \frac{2 \pi f l}{c} \left.\right)}}$$
$l=10000m$ (unrealistic but ignore)

```
x=linspace(0,10000000000,20000000);
q=(real(50.*(125 + 50i.*(tan((10000.*pi.*x)./149896229)))./ (50 + 125i.* (tan((10000.*pi.*x) ./149896229)))) ./(20+((50.*(125 + 50i.*(tan((10000.*pi.*x) ./149896229) ))./(50 + 125i.* (tan((10000.*pi.*x) ./149896229) ))))));
q(1) = 2; // DC component is double 
w=cat(2, q, conj(flip(q)));
w(end) = [];
r=ifft(w);
plot(r)
```

[image]

Balanis' lossless dipole antenna (input impedance equation on Wikipedia) :

$$H(f) = \frac{{\frac {\eta _{0}}{2\pi \sin ^{2}\left({\tfrac {1}{2}}kL\right)}}{\Bigg \{}\gamma _{e}+\ln(kL)-\operatorname {Ci} (kL)+{}{\tfrac {1}{2}}\sin(kL)\,{\Big [}+\operatorname {Si} (2kL)-2\operatorname {Si} (kL)\ {\Big ]}\\{}+{}{\tfrac {1}{2}}\cos(kL)\,{\Big [}+\operatorname {Ci} (2kL)-2\operatorname {Ci} (kL)+\gamma _{e}+\ln \left({\tfrac {1}{2}}kL\right)\ {\Big ]}{\Bigg \}}\\}{{\frac {\eta _{0}}{2\pi \sin ^{2}\left({\tfrac {1}{2}}kL\right)}}{\Bigg \{}\gamma _{e}+\ln(kL)-\operatorname {Ci} (kL)+{}{\tfrac {1}{2}}\sin(kL)\,{\Big [}+\operatorname {Si} (2kL)-2\operatorname {Si} (kL)\ {\Big ]}\\{}+{}{\tfrac {1}{2}}\cos(kL)\,{\Big [}+\operatorname {Ci} (2kL)-2\operatorname {Ci} (kL)+\gamma _{e}+\ln \left({\tfrac {1}{2}}kL\right)\ {\Big ]}{\Bigg \}}\\+i{\frac {\eta _{0}}{2\pi \sin ^{2}\left({\tfrac {1}{2}}kL\right)}}{\Bigg \{}+\operatorname {Si} (kL)+{}{\tfrac {1}{2}}\cos(kL)\,{\Big [}-\operatorname {Si} (2kL)+2\operatorname {Si} (kL)\ {\Big ]}\\{}+{}{\tfrac {1}{2}}\sin(kL)\,{\Big [}+\operatorname {Ci} (2kL)-2\operatorname {Ci} (kL)+\operatorname {Ci} \left(2k{\tfrac {a^{2}}{L}}\right)\ {\Big ]}{\Bigg \}}}$$

With $k=\frac{2\pi f}{c}$ and $l=10000m$ and $a=0.01$

```
x=linspace(0,100000,200);
q=(59.9585.*(csc((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).^2).*(0.577216-cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*cos((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(0.577216-2.*cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+cosint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+log((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229))+log((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*sin((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(-2.*sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+sinint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229))))./(((59.9585.*i).*(csc((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).^2).*(0.5.*(cosint((pi.*x)./7494811450000000)-2.*cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+cosint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)).*sin((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*cos((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(2.*sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)-sinint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)))+59.9585.*(csc((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).^2).*(0.577216-cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*cos((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(0.577216-2.*cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+cosint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+log((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229))+log((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*sin((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(-2.*sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+sinint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)))));
q(1) = 2;
w=cat(2, q, conj(flip(q)));
w(end) = [];
r=ifft(w);
plot(r)
```

[image]

---

I do however get causal impulse responses for the current in both scenarios:

$$H(f) = \frac{1}{Z_{in}(f)} $$

```
x=linspace(0,10000000000,20000000);
q=(1./(((50.*(125 + 50i.*(tan((10000.*pi.*x) ./149896229) ))./(50 + 125i.* (tan((10000.*pi.*x) ./149896229) ))))));
q(1) = 0;
w=cat(2, q, conj(flip(q)));
w(end) = [];
r=ifft(w);
plot(r)
```

[image]

$$H(f) = \frac{1}{Z_{in}(f)} $$

```
x=linspace(0,100000,200);
q=1./(((59.9585.*i).*(csc((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).^2).*(0.5.*(cosint((pi.*x)./7494811450000000)-2.*cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+cosint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)).*sin((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*cos((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(2.*sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)-sinint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)))+59.9585.*(csc((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).^2).*(0.577216-cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*cos((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(0.577216-2.*cosint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+cosint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+log((0.05.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229))+log((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+0.5.*sin((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229).*(-2.*sinint((0.1.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)+sinint((0.2.*100000.*pi.*x)./149896229)))))
q(1) = 0;
w=cat(2, q, conj(flip(q)));
w(end) = [];
r=ifft(w);
plot(r)
```

[image]

I'm trying to get the voltage over the radiation resistance for the antenna, but obviously can't do it with a non causal impulse response because it's obviously wrong

Comment: Your whole code dump doesn't contain a single comment and the band worm lines of code are impossible to read. If you want to know whether something is causal or not, it would be helpful to post the actual equation that defines it. Impedance and Admittance  are inverses of each other and they can only be both causal if they are both  minimum phase.

Comment: @Hilmar I made the maths clearer; the code speaks for itself. Had to do IDFT because the inverse fourier and laplace transforms don't compute